# Суффикс "о" в сложных прилагательных

Tags: словообразование

В сложных прилагательных, образованных из двух основ, обозначающих равные понятия, например: литературно-музыкальный, литературно-художественный, торгово-промышленный, желудочно-кишечный, - буква "о" перед дефисом будет суффиксом? В Словаре Тихонова (в электронном виде) буква "о" выделена красным цветом и непонятно, является ли она суффиксом или нет.

Answer (score 2):

Традиционно в сложных словах  **о-е** принято в этом случае считать соединительной гласной (интерфиксом). Однако в школьной практике  -о- и -е- в сложных словах, образованных из сочетания «наречие + прилагательное» принято относить к суффиксам.

Мал**о**симпатичный, вечн**о**зелёный.

**Подробнее здесь:**

[Сложные слова. Соединительные гласные и суффиксы в сложных словах. Правописание гласных в сложных словах](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/39-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_fonetika__slovoobrazovanie__morfologiya_i_orfografiya/stages/651-28_slozhnye_slova_soedinitelnye_glasnye_i_suffiksy_v_slozhnyh_slovah_pravopisanie_glasnyh_v_slozhnyh_slovah.html)

[Слова с соединительной гласной «о» и «е»](https://ok.ru/dk?cmd=logExternal&st._aid=Conversations_Openlink&st.name=externalLinkRedirect&st.link=http%3A%2F%2Frusskiiyazyk.ru%2Fslovoobrazovanie%2Fslova-s-soedinitelnoy-glasnoy-o-i-e.html)

Answer (score 1):

Суффиксом, конечно. Словообразующим. Не окончанием же?! Флексию вообще выделяют только у склоняемых имен, ничего больше не остаётся.

Comment: Понятно, что не окончанием. просто нашла на сайте http://morphemeonline.ru/%D0%9B/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9 вот такой разбор слова

Comment: @Cтася =>   А, это надо было в текст вопроса вставить. Понимаете, какая штука, тут доказать что-либо очень сложно. Если считать, что составляющая "литературно" - наречие, то ни о какой "соединительной гласной" речи быть не может.   И я склонен считать именно наречием, потому что слово, "прицепляемое" спереди через дефис, обычно сохраняет исходную форму, никаких соединительных гласных не требует.   Сравните: "сине-зеленый" и "иссиня-зеленый". Во втором случае, "Я" - соединительная, так что ли? Ну а авторы вашего разбора, видимо, считают, что "литературно" порождено основой прилагаетельного.

Comment: То есть получается, что тут разные подходы к разбору сложных слов? Но в слове литературно не может же быть соединительной гласной? По логике с сине-зеленым и иссиня-черным "о" должна быть суффиксом.

Comment: @Cтася *Но в слове литературно не может же быть соединительной гласной?* - при моем подходе - нет. Но в принципе она возможна, например в сочетнаниях на "-ско": "купеческо-мещанский" - тут ничего не остается, как признать "О"  соединительной гласной.  Наречие бы было "купечески". У нас такой предопределенности нет. Почему я и сказал, тут зависит от подхода. А вообще, если это вопрос школьной или институтской программы, тут надо человека, знающего актуальные методики, я не силен.

Answer (score 0):

Словообразующим суффиксом в этих словах является -Н (-ЕНН). А гласная О в конце первой основы - интерфикс (или соединительная гласная, как говорят в школе). Потому она и выделена красным.

Если предположить, что составляющая "литературно-" - наречие, тогда надо будет включить в это предположение и составляющую "торгово-", а наречия "торгово" не бывает. Что позволяет нам исключить предположение о наречии даже без обращения к справочникам.

Ну, и так, для справки: флексии (окончания) в русском языке бывают не только у склоняемых имён, но и у спрягаемых глаголов.

Ну что же, **behemothus**, вы правы: всё следует подтверждать ссылками. Вот ссылка на *академический* источник, доказывающая наличие окончаний у спрягаемых глаголов: [Русская грамматика, система форм времени, § 1492](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1490-1515.html#1492). Копирую на всякий случай текст оттуда ещё и сюда:

> § 1492. Формы настоящего времени образуются путем присоединения **окончаний**, являющихся показателями лица и числа, к основе наст. вр. глаголов несов. вида [...].

(слово "окончаний" выделено мной - Хан)

И да, вопрос именно "в том": в исходном вопросе даны **три** факта языка (*литературно*-художественный, *торгово*-промышленный, *желудочно*-кишечный), и давайте не будем подгонять факты под гипотезу (выкидывая из исходника факты, которые нам не нравятся) - ваша гипотеза должна объяснять **все** представленные факты, а она не объясняет.

Comment: *тогда надо будет включить в это предположение и составляющую "торгово-", * - нет, "торгово" включать не надо. Это логика "за компанию повесился", и её тут никто не рассматривает. Вопрос именно в том, считать ли наречием "литературно", а **оно "бывает"**.

Comment: *Ну, и так, для справки: флексии (окончания) в русском языке бывают не только у склоняемых имён, но и у спрягаемых глаголов.* - Не надо таких "справок". У глаголов в настоящем времени по академическим понятиям - суффиксы.  Посмотрите определение "флексии", она служит исключительно для связи слов в предложении,  у глаголов  "окончания" выполняют куда более значимые функции. http://tutrus.com/morfemika/suffiksy-glagolov